# Do complex vectors remain on a plane when getting rotated?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors, linear-transformations, rotations

Thanks for reading.

I'm trying to better understand how rotation matrices work on complex-valued vectors.

Say we have the rotation matrix:

$R_\theta =\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & \ -sin(\theta)
\\ 
\sin(\theta)& \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$

This rotates a real-valued vector on the cartesian plane by $\theta$ degrees.

So, if we have a vector $\vec{v}$, and we compute $R_\theta \vec{v}$, the output is $\vec{v}$ but rotated by $\theta $ degrees couunter-clockwise .

However, now say $\vec{v}$ is allowed to have complex components.

If $\vec{v}$ is in $\mathbb{C}^2$, then we can picture it as really existing in $4D$ space, where there's a real $X$ direction, a real $Y$ direction, an imaginary $X$ direction and an imaginary $Y$ direction.

Let's say $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
3
\end{bmatrix}$, or something like that. The point is that its components are only real - it exists entirely on the real $(X,Y)$ plane.

When we rotate $\vec{v}$ by any amount, it'll stay on the real $(X,Y)$ plane. It won't ever rotate into any of the imaginary dimensions.

Similarly, say $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
2i\\ 
3i
\end{bmatrix}$.

Now once more, when we rotate $\vec{v}$ by any amount by multiplying it by $R_\theta$ on the left, it'll stay on the **imaginary** $(X,Y)$ plane. It won't ever rotate into any of the real dimensions.

But, now say  $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
(1+i)\\ 
(3)
\end{bmatrix}$.

...or something like that. The point is that it's $x$ and $y$ components have both real **and** imaginary components themselves.

Would a rotation *(multiplication by $R_\theta$ on the left)* still keep $\vec{v}$ on **some** plane, with the axes of that plane pointing into some combination of the imaginary and the real directions?

If that's the case, how could we find what that plane is?

---

**What I've done thus far:**

I'm tempted to answer yes to my question, and here's why.

When we have a vector

$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b
\end{bmatrix}$

and we rotate it by $90^0$, we end up with $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
-b\\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
-b\\ 
a
\end{bmatrix}$  and $\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ 
b
\end{bmatrix}$

are orthogonal directions, which very clearly could be made to define the axes of some plane.

If $a$ and $b$ were both real, then this quite obviously was the real $(X,Y)$ plane, and rotation by ANY angle would've kept the vector on this plane.

Now, say we have...
$\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
(2+3i)\\ 
(1+4i)
\end{bmatrix}$.

...or something similar, where its components have both imaginary and real parts, and we multiply $\vec{v}$ by the rotation matrix that corresponds to rotating by $90^0$:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(90) & \ -sin(90)
\\ 
\sin(90)& \cos(90)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
(2+3i)\\ 
(1+4i)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-(1+4i)\\ 
(2+3i)
\end{bmatrix}$

Those orthogonal directions, $\begin{bmatrix}
-(1+4i)\\ 
(2+3i)
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
(2+3i)\\ 
(1+4i)
\end{bmatrix}$ could also define some plane.

However, it's not clear to me that rotation by an angle less than $90^0$ would've kept $\vec{v}$ on that same plane...

Would it have?

Thanks!

*(If my question is unclear, please leave a comment!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would a rotation (multiplication by  on the left) still keep ⃗  on some plane, with the axes of that plane pointing into some combination of the imaginary and the real directions?

I guess by plane you mean $2$-dimensional real subspace?

View $\mathbb C^2$ as an $\mathbb R$ vector space.  Any two linearly independent vectors of any real vector space determine a plane. If they are linearly dependent, then there are many such planes to choose from. In either way, the transformation "keeps $v$ and $R_\theta(v)$ in a plane."

If you're trying to ask if the image of $R_\theta$ acting on $\mathbb C^2$ is $2$-real-dimensional, then of course not. It is a nonsingular transformation acting on a $4$-real-dimensional space. Its image will also be $4$ dimensional.

Comment: I believe the question is: for a given vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^4\cong\mathbb{R}^2\oplus \mathbb{R}^2$, does the image of $\theta \mapsto (R_{\theta} v_1, R_{\theta} v_2)$ lie in a two-dimensional linear subspace?

Comment: @user7530 The user writes: "$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(90) & \ -sin(90)
\\ 
\sin(90)& \cos(90)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
(2+3i)\\ 
(1+4i)
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-(1+4i)\\ 
(2+3i)
\end{bmatrix}$" which is not what you are conjecturing they mean, (which I believe is "apply the rotation to the two complex entries individually.) The appear to be simply treating the matrix as a $\mathbb C$-linear operator on $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: @user7530 that's exactly the question...if I understand the notation correctly. For a **specific** vector (with possibly complex components), does its multiplication by **any** rotation matrix $R_\theta$, regardless of what $\theta$ is, give us a vector that lies on the same plane? The same two-dimensional linear subspace?

Comment: @rschwieb you may be correct as well on what I mean...I'm not very good at understanding all the notation :( Also, thanks for your answer, +1, but I'm still confused since I don't know if you understood my question...

Comment: @JoshuaRonis What is "complex notation"?  It makes no difference if you are using $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, the matrix algebra is all the same...  If you meant "complex" in the literal english sense, then never mind :)

Comment: I mean what @user7530 wrote in his comment. Is the way I rewrote it in English in my response to his comment what you meant with your answer? Yep, I meant complex in the English sense! Still a high school student here!

Comment: @JoshuaRonis What you wrote in your post suggests you are just using a real $2\times 2$ matrix to multiply elements of $\mathbb C^2$ via matrix multiplication. My understanding (possibly wrong) of what user7530 wrote is that $R_\theta (a,b)$ for complex $a$ and $b$ would be $(R_\theta(a), R_\theta(b))\in \mathbb C^2$. These two operations are completely different, so I suggest you carefully determine which one you want to write about.

Comment: @JoshuaRonis Doing it the second way would send $(2+3i, 1+4i)$ to $(-3+2i, -4+i)$

Comment: @rschwieb Ah, sorry for the confusion, I mean $v_1$ and $v_2$ to be the real and imaginary parts of $v$ respectively (which I believe is the same as the OP's question)

Comment: In any case I believe the answer is "the orbit lies in a plane iff the real and imaginary parts of $v$ are linearly dependent" though I'm not seeing the proof

Comment: @user7530 Hmm, OK, thanks for clarifying. I will think about it. I don't see anything about separating the parts though...

Comment: @user7530 Orbit under the action of all rotations, you mean?

Comment: Yes all 2D rotations (where the same rotation acts on the real and imaginary part of the vector)

Comment: @user7530 okay so no, I don't mean what rscwieb **thought** user7530 meant in his comment, but I think I mean what  user7530  **actually** meant in his comment! Regardless, that last way of putting it is the best: does the entire **orbit** of any complex vector getting rotated by an angle of $\theta$, *which by entire orbit I mean we let $\theta$ range from $0$ to $360^0$*, lie in the same plane? Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @JoshuaRonis Can you rewrite your math so it actually reflects what you want, then?  This is very confusing when you say you want one thing but write another.

Comment: @rschwieb could you please do it, and I'll accept the edit? I'm not sure I'll do it correctly...I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @JoshuaRonis How can I? I am not very sure what you mean at all.  If it's a problem of formatting I'm sure we can tidy it up once you supply the raw material.

Comment: @rschwieb wait I'm a little confused...is there a part of my math that's incorrect? Also, should we continue this discussion in chat? Well, later today at least, I gtg right now, but I don't want to keep on cluttering up the comments...

Comment: @JoshuaRonis By all means create a chat. I'd be happy to do that. My very first comment in the thread here supports my original viewpoint of what you meant. If I've got your meaning wrong, then you'd have to rewrite that to be whatever you really meant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96326/discussion-between-joshua-ronis-and-rschwieb).